# Inserting ~3500 objects into OrientDB takes too long

Tags: orientdb

I have a three-node setup of OrientDB 2.1.2 using mostly default configuration (except for some options mentioned in "Performance Tuning").

In a particular operation using the Java Graph API I am generating 1745 vertex insertions and 1753 edge insertions, which takes between 6 to 7 seconds to complete (sometimes it takes up to 10 seconds).

I feel that this is far too long for this operation to complete. I tried adding/removing the "massive insert" intent, but it doesn't help that much.

Am I doing anything wrong / overlooking something? Is it normal for OrientDB to take up to 10 seconds to create ~3500 objects in the distributed setup?

Comment: Have you already tried asynchronous replication?

Comment: I did, but the improvement was not much (~5 secs).

Comment: Please could you try v2.1.3 just released? We highly improved asynchronous replication with CRUD operations, even if in your case I guess you're executing one or multiple transactions, so the improvement would be not such noticeable.

Comment: @Lvca just updated. I'm getting the exact same timings (no noticeable difference). Is this such an edge-case scenario that no one has ever felt the need to address this?

Comment: Do you have a piece of code to test?

Comment: @Lvca Yes, please check here: https://github.com/roystark2015/example-orientdb . Many thanks.

Comment: @Lvca have you had any chance of looking at the code?

Comment: I see you're doing also +1,745 lookup to check if the record already exist. That is a query, so the throughput decreases. I see also you are using 1 tx to commit everything. Could you please try to commit/begin every 500 vertices?

Comment: @Lvca I see... But if I commit every X vertices, won't I end up having "grabage" in the database in case one of the transactions fails?

Comment: @Lvca And about the lookups... Is there any way I could improve that? Basically, what I need is an UPSERT.

Comment: Have you tried on using the UPSERT?

Comment: @Lvca I can't use UPSERT from the Java API as it is not exposed.

Comment: You could execute an UPSERT through a command, but I doubt performance would be better.

Comment: @Lvca so, how can I improve on this? Is this scenario such an edge case that no one has noticed this before?

Comment: OrientDB uses distributed transactions when you add edges to maintain consistency, that's why is slower in not that fast in distributed mode. We're working on making such operation faster, but this will be in v3.0, sorry.

Comment: In v2.2 we allowed to modify graph in non transaction and it's safe unless your JVM is killed. No Tx + WAL disabled allows you to get about 50k edges/sec